# Looping Ajax call

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I have a simple Ajax call and for some reason I am unable to get the call to refresh the data properly.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
    var myFunction = $(document).ready(function(){
      $("#div1").load("feeds.php");
    });
    setInterval(myFunction, 1000);
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>

  </body>
</html>
```

If I cut out of my attempt at an interval, It loads, but only once.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#div1").load("feeds.php");
});
```

Any ideas where I am going on? My understanding of Ajax is a work in progress.

Thanks!

Comment: Trying to loop logic that performs asynchronously with setInterval, your going to have a bad time.  Instead look into placing the logic in a function and attach a success method to the ajax call which recursively calls the method for the logical loop.

Comment: @Taplar would you mind providing an example? Like I said, my Ajax understanding is minimal but growing, I can figure it out much quicker with an example - Doesn't have to be the answer to my question, but something to get the gears turning.

Comment: `setInterval` requires a function as the first argument. `myFunction` is not a function but an object.

Comment: @RobertDickey Take a look at http://api.jquery.com/deferred.then/ for some ideas then (no pun intended).

Comment: @Taplar I looked at it the .then, and I can tell it is useful for reporting/knowing what is going on, but I can't seem to notice anything about refreshing the data/looping..Are you sure something is there? Its possible im missing it or not digging deep enough.

Comment: Are you expecting the logic to load, process response, wait a second, and then repeat?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$(document).ready(...)` returns a jQuery object - so it can't be used as the argument to setInterval, which expects a function as it's first argument

Your code needs to be written

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    function myFunction(){
        $("#div1").load("feeds.php");
    }
    setInterval(myFunction, 1000);
});
```

or even

```
function myFunction(){
    $("#div1").load("feeds.php");
}
$(document).ready(function() {
    setInterval(myFunction, 1000);
});
```

This way, myFunction is globally visible

You also need to have an element with id=div1 for this code to work

so: the whole thing looks like

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        function myFunction(){
            $("#div1").load("feeds.php");
        }
        $(document).ready(function() {
            setInterval(myFunction, 1000);
        });
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="div1"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I copied the code to test it, and it doesn't return any results after 1000MS, Am I supposed to trigger it somehow?

Comment: `it doesn't return any results` - your original code didn't even look like it was interested in returning results .... what results are you expecting every 1000ms? the result of .load? read .load documentation to see how you use it - .load loads the resultant data into the targetted element - the problem is, you have no element with id='div1'

Comment: My example in my post above is, despite alot of criticism currently working without the interval. All I am attempting to do is get it to where it updates at an interval. I can place a button, and use OnClick to trigger it, and it functions as I would like..But I am asking how get it going automatically. I certainly appreciate your help, but so many people tell me to look up the same things I already have. A working example would teach me much quicker

Comment: I doubt your code does anything because you have no element with `id="div1"`

Comment: Believe me, It works. div1 is located on the feeds.php page that isn't listed. I can modify it, refresh my code, and it works perfectly. Perhaps it shouldn't be working, but it is.

Comment: If what you've shown in your question is the exact code in your "working" page, then you have a version of jQuery that seems to predict that div1 is in an external file, and knows exactly where your want to place the result of reading `feeds.php` despite the selected element initially being totally absent from the DOM - that's an interesting majick feat by that version of jQuery

Comment: if I run `$("#div1").load("feeds.php");` in a page with no `id=div1` the `load` is not even started - so, again, you either have a majick version of jQuery, or you've missed something important when you've "minimised" the code for the question, and that is the target of the .laod

Comment: I ran your code, and it worked - However - I just noticed that I do not have a div1 in feeds.php. Instead, I believe that it is loading the entire page - as it also loads text outside of the div i specified. Is that possible? a default behavior? possibly a bug? There ISN'T anything else to the code than what I posted. nothing minimized.

Comment: I now see why my code shouldn't have been working - I cannot explain why or how it did.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest something like the following instead of using setInterval.

```js
jQuery(function($){
  //name the method to recursively call it, and invoke it immediately
  (function refreshFeeds(failureCount){
    //if the load failed 5 times in a row, stop trying, something is wrong
    if (failureCount < 5){
      $('#div1').load('feeds.php').then(function success(){
        //request was good, reset failures and execute again after a second
        setTimeout(function(){ refreshFeeds(0); }, 1000);
      }, function error(){
        //request was bad, increment the failure count and execute again after a second
        setTimeout(function(){ refreshFeeds(failureCount + 1); }, 1000);
      } );
    } else {
      console.log('Feeds failed to load 5 times.  Terminating request loop.');
    }
  })(0);
});
```

Comment: Added failure count logic to kill it if it keeps failing.  If you don't care about failures that part could of course be removed.

Answer (score 0):

You're calling your function on the `$(document).ready()` event, which will be called only once when the DOM is loaded. You don't need that part.

```
var myFunction = function(){
    $("#div1").load("feeds.php");
};
```

Or, the more common syntax

```
function myFunction(){
    $("#div1").load("feeds.php");
};
```

Comment: This answer does not currently address his looping concern.

Comment: The looping isn't really where it's going wrong though. If it wasn't wrapped in $(document).ready() it would run more than once.

Comment: I made the changes as suggested, but I'm not sure how to trigger it.

Comment: Well, without the $(document).ready(), the setInterval should work.

Comment: @dave thank you very much for your help! you helped me closer to an answer.